# How to verify rotation relation between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Suppose we have two matrices. How do we verify that one of them is related to the other by a rotation only, i.e.
$$AU = B,$$ where $UU^T=I$.

One way I can think of is to form $AA^T$ and $BB^T$ and see if they are equal. 
But the question is how to check this property without the need to multiply matrices to their transpose.

One way would be to solve  the system of equations $AU=B$ for $U$ and then check if $U$ is orthonormal.  But there should be other easier ways too. I am looking for that.

Follow-up: How doe singular value/vectors of $A$ and $B$ relate?

Comment: You could just check that $A^{-1}B$ is a rotation. Or solve $A u_k =  B e_k$ and check that the $u_k$ are orthonormal.

Comment: A is not a squared matrix. It could be nonsingular too. By looking at singular decomposition of both, could this be checked?

Comment: "There should be an easier way": I don't think it gets easier that finding $AA^T$ and $BB^T$. Also, note that if you solve for $U$, then unless $A,B$ are tall matrices of full rank, you will have multiple solutions.

Comment: My goal is not to solve for $U$. The goal is to make sure if such $U$ exists.